# How to compute result from two values in same column while checking multiple conditions in other columns in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I'm stuck and not sure how to compute the "number of female clients" (my desired result is the last column of table I provided) for each partner during each fiscal year using the annual impact values with the metric names "% Female Clients" and "Total Clients" (% female  client * total clients = number of female clients) in Power BI. I would really appreciate any tips or advice. Thanks so much for taking the time to review my problem.  Below is an image and text of my table.

[image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIMCd.png)

Partner_Account__c  Metric_Name__c  Fiscal_Year__c  Annual_Impact__c    #_OF_FEMALE_CLIENTS
A                   % Female Clients    FY 20-21    70%     700
A                   Total Clients           FY 20-21    1000
A                   % Female Clients    FY 21-22    80%     1600
A                   Total Clients           FY 21-22    2000
B                   % Female Clients    FY 20-21    50%     500
B                   Total Clients           FY 20-21    1000
B                   % Female Clients    FY 21-22    60%     1200
B                   Total Clients           FY 21-22    2000

I tried creating multiple new measurements in PowerBI using LOOKUPVALUE() and FILTER() and CALCULATE(SUM()) but wasn't able to recreate the last column in the table.